# In java, when variables such as Long, long, Double ,double are autoboxing or unboxing, is reading or writing operation atomic?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic, jls, java-memory-model

I know [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html):

> Reads and writes are atomic for reference variables and for most primitive variables (all types except long and double).
>   Reads and writes are atomic for all variables declared volatile (including long and double variables).

But I want to know 
When variables such as Long, long, Double ,double are autoboxing or unboxing, is reading or writing operation atomic?

For example:

```
private Long a;    
private long b;    
private Double c;    
private double d;

a = 2; //is this operation atomic?    
b = a; //is this operation atomic?    
d = 3;    
c = d; //is this operation atomic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> Reads and writes are atomic for reference variables and for most primitive variables (all types except long and double)

```
a = 2;
```

This is a write to a reference variable, so it's atomic

```
b = a;
```

This is equivalent to

```
read a
call a.longValue()
assign result to b
```

So this reads a reference variable (atomic), then gets an immutable long value from the Long object (so atomicity is irrelevant) and writes to a long primitive (so no guarantee to be atomic)

```
d = 3;
```

This writes to a primitive double (so no guarantee to be atomic)

```
c = d;
```

This is equivalent to

```
read d
call Double.valueOf(value)
assign result to b
```

So this reads from a primitive double (so no guarantee to be atomic), then transforms the value to a Double and writes that reference to a reference variable (atomic)

Comment: If you've quoted something you should cite the source.

Comment: The source is the OP's question. I thought that was obvious.

Comment: I didn't know i should cite the source. This is the source i referred  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Comment: @5969bruce You should not only cite the source, you should indicate the quotation by using quote formatting.

Comment: Here is a more detailed explanation from Oracle for Java 8 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html Specifically the following "Implementations of the Java Virtual Machine are encouraged to avoid splitting 64-bit values where possible. Programmers are encouraged to declare shared 64-bit values as volatile or synchronize their programs correctly to avoid possible complications."